# Forward any Nodejs request to another servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, proxy, microservices

Imagine I want to implement API Gateway for microservices. I have this type of route in gateway:

```
app.all('/api/users-service/*', (req, res, next) => {

});
```

What I want to do is forward given `req` to service without knowing it's `GET`, `POST` or something else. I also may need to build two different request, forward them to two different services and return merged response in gateway. something like that:

```
app.all('/api/users-service/*', (req, res, next) => {
    const user = await request(req, 'http://first-service/api/user/' + req.body.userId);
    const products = await request(req, 'http://second-service/api/products');
    res.status(200).json({
        user: user,
        products: products
    });
});
```

I know it's bad example but hope you will understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to forward request, what is the best way, what npm package should I use? how to use it? so that I can use given request and create another request or requests.

Comment: the function you are passing the `req` to, accepts what? `request` module doesnt work that way.

Comment: I know, I'm just trying to explain what I am trying to achieve

Comment: you will have to manually build the request-option for request from `req` object.

Comment: The term for what you're looking for is a "proxy".  You can get pre-made proxy servers that only have to be configured (such as nginx) or you can get modules you can use in node.js that you can configure and enable in your node.js code.  Just search NPM for "proxy" and you will find lots of modules there.  Or, you can build your own which will involve examining the incoming request, setting up a matching outgoing request and then piping the response back to the originator.

Comment: you can use Nginx's SSI or varnish's ESI to accomplish the merge of different requests into single response. your users-service could do some its own specific work and generate response with include instructions to off-load subsequent requests to other services.

Comment: what if I need authentication middleware inside that api gateway? will nginx still be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely forward requests to other services, in some cases a proxy will be exactly what you need but in others, you may want to do something more sophisticated like process requests and responses.

In this case you could try something like below:

```
const rp = require("request-promise-native");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const userServiceRootUrl = "http://first-service/api/user/";
const productServiceRootUrl = "http://second-service/api/products/";

app.all("/api/users-service/*", bodyParser.json(), async (req, res) => {
    console.log("/api/users-service/ path:", req.params[0]);
    const user = await rp({ baseUrl: userServiceRootUrl, url: req.params[0], body: req.body, json: true, method: req.method });
    const products = await rp({ url: productServiceRootUrl });
    res.status(200).json({
        user: user,
        products: products
    });
});
```

In this example we're using [request-promise-native](https://github.com/request/request-promise-native) as it gives us a promise based api, you could also use node-fetch or some other http client.

What you can also do in this case is create mock endpoints in your express server to test response handling, for example:

```
app.all("/api/user/*", bodyParser.json(), async (req, res) => { 
    console.log("/api/user/", req.path);
    res.json( { name: "joe smith" })
});

app.all("/api/products/", bodyParser.json(), async (req, res) => { 
    console.log("/api/products/", req.path);
    res.json( [{ id: 1, name: "some product" }]);
});
```

Then simply change your userServiceRootUrl and productServiceRootUrl as appropriate, e.g.

```
http://localhost:<port>/api/user/
http://localhost:<port>/api/products/
```